# transform.rotate not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a simple 2d space shooter. I have created an asteroid and want to make it rotate. So I attached a script to it and put it as this (see below) yet the image doesn't rotate.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {
    void update () {
        transform.Rotate (0, 90 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "update()" to "Update()"

If that code was copy pasted then clearly that is the problem.

Comment: awesome thank you that worked. Cant believe I didn't see that!

Comment: @MarkHughes88 Honestly I wasn't expecting that to fix the problem but you never know. I realized that Unity doesn't actually print that error since the syntax is perfectly correct, you defined a function called update, no problem with that.